# Ansible connection becomes unreachble after a while

Tags: shell, ssh, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I am running a task in ansible, and the task runs a script present on a remote host.

```
---
- hosts: remote_host
  become: yes
  gather_facts: true
  connection: ssh

  tasks:
    - name: Run a script
      shell: bash /root/script.sh
```

This initially establishes a connection successfully, and the task runs the script for a while, before the task fails with an "unreachable" error.

The ansible playbook itself is triggered by a Jenkins job, and the duration of run is passed as a Jenkins parameter.
When I pass the duration as 30 minutes, it runs throughout without interruptions.

But it fails after a while for a 1 hour duration.
Could this be an issue with maintaining the connection for that long?

Comment: What is the exact error you get ? Are your running the task directly on the Jenkins master or on a slave ? Are your sure it does not come from Jenkins itself ? Could it be a connection (timeout/inactive) problem between the master and the slave ?

Comment: Hello @Zeitounator, Everything is being run on the master. The agent { label 'master' } is defined at the level below the 'pipeline' block

Answer (score 0):

It might be breaking from default connection timeout if it takes sometime at a place somewhere while executing.